# Overloading the -> and = operators for a class template to differentiate between read and write operations on members of a member struct

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, semaphore

I am working on a C++ project where multiple processes need to read and interact with data concurrently across different machines using shared memory.  I've created a class template that can be applied to any struct. The user can create an instance of the class using a single command and then interact with the member struct using the vanilla _> operator. The class template handles the synchronization of concurrent access to memory using  a binary semaphore.

However, I'd like to use more complex semaphore operations that require differentiating between read and write operations. I would like to overload the "=" operator to accomplish this but as of now the only approach I can find requires creating a wrapper for each member of the struct, making it tedious and impractical. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
struct dataset {
    int int1;
    double dbl1;
};

template <typename S>
class MyClass {

public:
    S* data;
    MyClass<S>(args)
    {

    // memory mapping, etc.
    // data is cast to memory location
    // sem_ptr is cast to memory location of semaphore

 
    }
    Proxy<S> operator->() {
        return *(new Proxy<s>(data, sem_ptr);
    }
private:
    sem_t* semptr;
    // other variables relating to shared memory

};
template <typename T>
class Proxy
{
public:
   Proxy(T* ptr, sem_t* sem) : ptr_(ptr), sem_(sem)
   {
      sem_wait(sem_);
   }

   ~Proxy()
   {
      sem_post(sem_);
   }

   T* operator->()
   { 
      return ptr_;
   }
private:
   T* ptr_;
   sem_t* sem_;

};
```

This code works fine but it does not differentiate between read and write.

Doing so requires something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(T& value, sem_t* sem) : value_(value), sem_(sem) {}

    operator T() const {
        // read operations
        return value_;
    }

    Wrapper& operator=(const T& other) {
        sem_wait(sem_);
        value_ = other;
        sem_post(sem_);
        return *this;
    }
```

and including

```
Wrapper<typename S::type1> int1() {
        return Wrapper<typename S::type1>(data->int1, sem_ptr);
    }

    Wrapper<typename S::type2> dbl1() {
        return Wrapper<typename S::type2>(data->dbl1, sem_ptr);
    }
```

in the class definition for every member of S, which defeats the original purpose.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality without having to modify the original struct or wrap each member in a separate type? Ideally, I would like to use the vanilla -> and = operators and maintain the original member names while making the solution applicable to any struct cast to memory within a class.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

I'm pretty new to C++ so please be understanding.

Comment: *I would like to overload the "=" operator to accomplish this* -- It is not a good idea to use `operator=` to implement business logic that could have side-effects.  `Wrapper& operator=(const T& other)` -- if `T` is a `Wrapper`, you now have to know when and where *all* assignments are being done, by you explicitly, or by the compiler.   The toughest bugs to hunt down are ones where the assignment operator is used this way, where you are not in full control where it occurs.

Comment: Instead, the good, old-fashioned `assign()` function should be implemented.  Also note, you now have to write a copy constructor along with the assignment operator.  Using the assignment operator to assign to totally different types, for example an `int` to a `BigInteger` object -- that's perfectly ok.  But assigning same or derived types using the assignment operator -- you are setting yourself up for a lot of pain when your program behaves in ways you didn't expect.

Comment: Traditionally, the overloaded operators of choice for read and write are `operator>>` and `operator<<`.

Comment: What you can do is to write two overloads, one const-qualified, the other not. This will at least let you distinguish between writeablw and not writable, but not between written and read-only.